# video background switch to photo on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, background, switch-statement

I got a quick question. I'm working on my website and I put a video in background, which work perfect, on the landing page here's the code:

```
<a id="P2" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=something',containment:'#home',autoPlay:true, mute:false, startAt:43, loop:true, opacity:1}"></a>
```

But for mobile user, any from tablet to smartphone, I would like to load a slider in background which I have. So what is the lither and cleaner way to put a Javascript condition for that task?

Comment: Can you show us some research effort?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).on('load resize',function(){
        if($(window).width() < 768){
            //add slideshow function here
        } else {
        //video function here
        }
    });
    });
```

This will trigger on screen width (and either on load or user re-sizing).  If you want to trigger on device type, you can replace the `if` statement with device ids.  There's no shortage of answers on here about how to detect devices.